# Calling class methods inside javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js, this

This is a Vue class. The method `signOut()` should fire when the timer ticks. The timer works, except the call `signOut()`.

The problem is with accessing the class method. I'm confused with `this`, self and access modifiers.
I tried with `this.signOut()` but it does not work.

How can I call the method `signOut`?

```js
"use strict";

(async (globals, config, loader, application) => {

    const storageLocal = await loader.services.storage.local.getAsync();

    class HeaderComponent {
        #foo = a;

        constructor(tag) {
            this.tag = tag;

            this.timer();
        }

        signOut() {
            storageLocal.delete('account');
            window.location = '/signin.html';
        }

        timer() {
            //document.getElementById("timer"), 
            var counter = -1;
            var timeout;
            var startTimer = function timer() {
                counter++;
                console.log(counter);

                signOut(); //<- error can't call class method
                timeout = setTimeout(timer, 10000);
            };

            function resetTimer() {
                // here you reset the timer...
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                counter = -1;
                startTimer();
                //... and also you could start again some other action
            }

            document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer);
            document.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer);
            startTimer();
        }

        data() {
            return { account: storageLocal.account };
        }
    }

    const component = new HeaderComponent('component-header')
    loader.components.set(component.tag, component);

})(window, window.config, window.loader, window.application);
```

Please note:

```js
        signOut() {
            storageLocal.delete('account');
            window.location = '/signin.html';
        }

        timer() {
            //document.getElementById("timer"), 
            var counter = -1;
            var timeout;
            var startTimer = function timer() {
```

as you can see 'signOut()' is 2 levels below active functions. The logic says it would work like `this.parent.signOut()` but it DOES NOT !

EDIT3: `this.signOut();` will produce

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signOut' of undefined
    at timer (header.js:30)
    at HTMLDocument.resetTimer
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't automatically infer `this` as a prefix like C#, you want to use `this.signOut()` instead of just `signOut()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `function` creates a new context. You need to switch to arrow function and use `this.signOut()`. Simplified example:

```
  timer() {
    var counter = -1;
    var timeout;
    var startTimer = () => {
      counter++;
      console.log(counter);

      this.signOut();
      timeout = setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
    };

    setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
  }
```

Moreover, you have two `signOut()` methods defined in one class.

Comment: youre right . iremoved second method. still this.signOut(); doesnt work for me ((

Comment: Even after replacing function with arrow function as I shown above?

Comment: Actualy it works , sorry. But the timer fires immediatelly, not after xx seconds. how can i set it to run AFTER xx seconds not imediatelly

Comment: You can call `startTimeout` in a `setTimeout()`. See live demo: https://repl.it/repls/SuperficialPrettyBookmarks. If it works, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need `this` and call it like `this.signOut()`

Comment: doesnt help at all (

Answer (score 0):

The `startTimer`-function does not run in the context of the `HeaderComponent`'s instance. 
 `this` in `startTimer` will point to `window` when it's executed as a handler in `setTimeout`.

In order to access the the instance of `HeaderComponent`, either use an arrow function (as pointed out in an earlier answer. See also [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) which will point `this` to the outer context (which is `HeaderComponent`'s instance) or define an identifier in `timer` which points to the instance (eg. `const self = this;`) and use `self` instead of `this` in `startTimer`.

To apply this to your example (for the sake of consistency, I used `var` instead of `const`):

```js
        timer() {
            var counter = -1;
            var timeout;
            var self = this;
            var startTimer = function() { // Don't use a named function here, it only leads to more confusion
                counter++;
                console.log(counter);

                self.signOut(); // Use `this` of the outer context
                timeout = setTimeout(startTimer, 10000);  // Use the declared identifier
            };

            // Rest of the method
        }
```

`this` is Javascript may be a bit confusing to those who come from different programming languages. If you want to get into more detail, I recommend reading into the [MDN reference for `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and into [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: but where do i put 'const self = this;' inside constructor or outside? I've tried everything without luck

Comment: In the outer `timer`-function and then call `self.signOut()` in the inner `timer`-function.

Comment: hmm, when i put const self = this; just aboce 
      timer() function then again i get error...

Comment: I've added the applied example to the answer